# What amount of light energy is required to produce one O2 molecule? How about one molecule of NADPH?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis, light

I know that for each O2 molecule, a total of 8 photons are required (4 per photosystem). Would the amount of light energy required be E=hc/wavelength using 680 and 700? Or would the energy from the initial incident light need to be taken into account (as in when light initially hits the photosystem and gets funneled down)?

Additionally, I know that one NADPH  is produced per 2 electrons. I am puzzled as to how this can be transformed into light energy? Would the amount of light energy required be that of PSI and PSII once again, due to the Z-scheme that ultimately leads to the NADPH production?

I appreciate any help.